# How to create 2 dimention Array that excludes value null

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on Array question.
I have an Array 
`String [] x= {"no", "i", "in" , "eye"};`
I need to create second dimension that that count characters in each value and repeats the element N number of times. N is the length of the element.
For example:

```
[no] ->[no][no] 
[i] -> [i]
[in] ->[in][in]
[eye] ->[eye][eye][eye].
```

I have created the following code to solve this problem:

```
  public class targil_2_4 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    String [] x= {"no", "i", "in" , "eye"};
    String [][] y = new String [x.length][];               
    for(int i=0; i<=x.length-1; i++){         
        y[i]= new String [x[i].length()];

            for(int j=0; j<i; j++){ 

                for(int b=0; b<=y[i].length-1; b++){ 

                    if(x[i] == null){break;}
                    else{
            y[i][j]= x[i];
                    }

                    }

                 System.out.println(x[i]+ " "+Arrays.toString(y[i]));

                }         
        }    
}
```

}

but i get values like [no] ->[no][no][null] :

```
[i]
[in, null]
[in, in]
[eye, null, null]
[eye, eye, null]
[eye, eye, eye]
```

How can i eliminate the lines that have value 'null' or maybe other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you using `x[i].length()` as the array length, but looping `i` times?

Comment: @JonSkeet OP wants to create the copies equals to  given string length

Comment: Hint: you want us to spend our time to help you. So you please take the 1 minute it takes to properly format/indent your source code. Alone the fact that your code is so hard to read costs *us* more time than it ought to be. And you know: if you would write down your code in a more readable way, you might be able to find the bugs in your code more quickly, too!

Comment: @PavneetSingh: Yup, so why is the OP *populating* the copies according to the index? Basically, the second loop condition is wrong... the loop should be `for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length(); j++) { y[i][j] = x[i]; }`. No need to check if `x[i]` is null, as if it is the earlier code would have thrown an exception anyway...

Comment: @JonSkeet than's one the problem , maybe OP thought it will print the whole array somehow

Comment: @JonSkeet why you solving this in comment , you are getting more up-votes than answers :P:P

Comment: You should tried to add comment to your code to remember what your are doing on each step. I see one loop that could be removed easily. And you null test is not necessary. But you need to think about what you want then how you can do it.

Comment: Hallo GostCat, tnx for a feedback. I will pay attention to it in the future.

Comment: @ElBundy: Rather than paying attention to it in the *future*, why not pay attention to it now? Edit your question to show the formatted code.

Comment: @PavneetSingh: I don't have the time to write up a full answer, and with the question in its current form in terms of formatting, it's not ideal anyway... but if just one brief comment is able to help the OP enough, that doesn't feel like it's worth an answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet i agree question quality is bad that's why i didn't try to answer it ,but i just said from an answerer point of view(i am one too :) ) because it may effect the future up-votes and i thought u have solved it so post it and have the cake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solution. You just have to do the following things :

1. Iterate over each entry of **x**.
2. Create an array( **y[i]** ) of the length which is equal to the the length of the element **x[i]**. So that you can repeat the element **x[i]** N times. Where N is the length of **x[i]**.
3. For each entry( **y[i][j]** ) of the array( **y[i]** ), set the value to **x[i]**.

Please refer to the numbering in the comments for better understanding.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] x = {"no", "i", "in", "eye"};
        String[][] y = new String[x.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i <= x.length - 1; i++) //1
        {
            y[i] = new String[x[i].length()]; //2

            for (int j = 0; j < y[i].length; ++j) 
            {
                y[i][j] = x[i]; //3
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(y[i]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, try to explain why this is a better solution, this is a newbie trying to learn, giving him some code won't help him

Answer (score 2):

You are **over-complicating** things:

```
for(int i=0; i<=x.length-1; i++) { // to iterate over the content of x
  y[i]= new String [x[i].length()]; 
  for(int j=0; j<x[i].length(); j++) { // iterate over the new array
    y[i][j]= x[i];     // and for each position in that array: fetch corresponding value from input array x
  }
}
```

should be doing it.

You see, your input array doesn't contain *any* nulls. So you just iterate that array; and for each entry *E* in that array, you determine the length of *E*; and then you create "length" copies of *E*.

And for the record: you wouldn't need us to solve such problems. You could easily run your code in a debugger to figure what is going on; or add print statements to understand what it is happening at runtime!

Comment: If I may suggest adding some comment on what each loops does (or adding a number pointing at your explanations).

Comment: @AxelH Did so. Although (imho), the text below the code snippets should nicely explain what the code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    String [] x= {"no", "i", "in" , "eye"};
    String[][] y = Stream.of(x)
        .map(s -> IntStream.range(0, s.length())
            .mapToObj(i -> s).toArray(String[]::new))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
    for (String[] a : y)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

result:

```
[no, no]
[i]
[in, in]
[eye, eye, eye]
```

Comment: Great. Throwing a complicated 4-line-stream operation at a total newbie who is unable to iterate/setup arrays using simple **for loops** ...

Answer (score 0):

You get nulls because in this line you check them and do nothing

if(x[i] == null){break;}

If you want to eliminate the nulls, just do it instead of breaking

Comment: Actually, that is not his problem.